# How to play audio files served from Rails / Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model that accepts audio file uploads (using Rails 5.2.2, active_storage).  To test things out I made a view that simply creates a play button for each one:

```html
<% @page.uploads.each do |upload| %>
    <div class="player btn btn-outline-secondary">
        <%= audio_tag rails_blob_url upload %>
        Play
    </div>
<% end %>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".player").click(function() {
        $(this).children('audio')[0].play();
    });
});          
</script>
```

This works great, but after 5 minutes it stops working, hitting the buttons no longer play the sounds and page must be refreshed to work again. (at least in Chrome and FireFox, Safari seems to continue working).

I think it has something to do with the redirect URLs generated by active storage expiring after 5 minutes... but I thought the rails_blob_url always returned a fresh URL to the file. Does this look like the correct approach, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the expiration time for active storage like this

```
# config/initializers/active_storage.rb
ActiveStorage::Service.url_expires_in = 1.hour
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  It seems to work as it looks like browser is preloading and then trying the URL again after it expired.  Another solution I discovered is adding .load(); before the .play();  which forces load from scratch, although adds some latency.  In the end I started using the howler.js library for playing the sounds which works great.